# Passing the variables from from jquery to rails controller

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I need to pass a variable which is captured from client side via jquery to controller, so that it can be used in the server side. After googling a bit, I found that we can pass it via an Ajax call.

**routes.rb**

```
get "mymethod?Id=", :to => "sample#mymethod"
```

**j1.js**

```
$(function(){

var test = 1;

$(.btn).click(function(){

  $.ajax({
           url: '/mymethod?Id='+ test,
           success: function(data) {
                 }
         });
    });

});
```

**sample_controller.rb**

```
def mymethod
 session[:Id] = params["Id"];
end
```

When I try to use session[:Id], it is always nil.

Any ideas,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make a GET request in jquery you'd be better off doing:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/mymethod',
    success: function(data){ // anything },
    data: { Id: test }
});
```

Because it urlencode and format the parameters correctly for you.

In rails, remove the reference to the Id in `routes.rb` and just use the `params` dictionary in your controller to access the variable Id (info here: http://rails.nuvvo.com/lesson/6371-action-controller-parameters)

Comment: Thank you nick. This is what I was looking for. Now I can see the value in the session. Since I am new to rails, please dont mind if this is a silly question.. I think "GET" requires a template/view for the action.. so I just changed the ajax request to "post", and changed the routes.rb file. Now again the session is not getting updated. Do you see any catch