# Passing JQuery Datepicker Data to Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I'm new to Rails and JQuery so I'll try to explain this as best I can. I'm trying to pass my JQuery datepicker values to my rails controller.  The page has data on it that I want the user to be able to filter based on a date range.  There are a number of different posts on this subject:

[Passing the variables from from jquery to rails controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211433/passing-the-variables-from-from-jquery-to-rails-controller)

[How to pass variables from AJAX form into controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842978/how-to-pass-variables-from-ajax-form-into-controller)

I have tried to follow the guidance of these posts, but I'm still having trouble.

Here is my partial _**dateFilter.html.erb** =>

```
    <%= form_tag({:controller => 'events', :action => 'dateFilter', :class => 'date_form'}, :remote => true) do %>
    <%= datepicker_input "event", :start_date, :class => 'dateFilter', :dateFormat => 'mm/dd/y' %>
    <%= datepicker_input "event", :end_date, :class => 'dateFilter', :dateFormat => 'mm/dd/y' %>
    <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
    <% end %>
```

Here is the generated **HTML** =>

```
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/events/dateFilter?class=date_form" data-remote="true" method="post">
    <input class="dateFilter" id="event_start_date" name="event[start_date]" size="30" type="text" /><script type="text/javascript">

   //<![CDATA[
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery('#event_start_date').datepicker({"dateFormat":"mm/dd/y"})});
   //]]>
   </script>

   <input class="dateFilter" id="event_end_date" name="event[end_date]" size="30" type="text" /><script type="text/javascript">

   //<![CDATA[
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery('#event_end_date').datepicker({"dateFormat":"mm/dd/y"})});
   //]]>
   </script>

   <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
   </form>
```

Here is the **dateFilter.js.erb** =>

```
$('.dateFilter').append('<%= escape_javascript(render(@events)) %>');
```

Here is the **events_controller** =>

```
 def dateFilter
   @events = Event.find(:all, :conditions => ["EVENT_DATE_TIME_LOCAL BETWEEN ? AND ?", params[:start_date], params[:end_date]])

  respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @events }
      format.js
  end
end
```

Finally here is the **application.js** =>

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#date_form').submit(function (){  

    $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: "/events/dateFilter", 
     beforeSend: function (xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript");},
     data: { 'start_date' : $("input[name='event[start_date]']").datepicker(), 'end_date' : $("input[name='event[end_date]']").datepicker()}
     success: function(data) { <%= render "events/dateFilter" %>}
    });

 });
```

This is **log data** from the server =>

```
Started POST "/events/dateFilter?class=date_form" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-12 15:09:39 -0500
Processing by EventsController#dateFilter as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"J/HU+DxNmIwEhu3keN071k6MGCCD/n/1UhXUD0MkH1Q=", "event"=>{"start_date"=>"12/06/12", "end_date"=>"12/13/12"}, "commit"=>"Submit", "class"=>"date_form"}
  Event Load (1.7ms)  SELECT "TBLEVENT".* FROM "TBLEVENT" WHERE (EVENT_DATE_TIME_LOCAL BETWEEN NULL AND NULL)
  Rendered collection (0.0ms)
  Rendered events/dateFilter.js.erb (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 3.4ms | ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)
```

One of the problems is that I keep getting "NULL" for the values of data I am trying to pass.  I'm not even sure that I am going about this correctly, any help/feedback on this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your log data, this is in the `Parameters`:

```
"event"=>{"start_date"=>"12/06/12", "end_date"=>"12/13/12"}
```

which means `start_date` and `end_date` are in a Hash called `event`, so your controller should look like this:

```
def dateFilter
    eventIn = params[:event]
    @events = Event.find(:all, :conditions => ["EVENT_DATE_TIME_LOCAL BETWEEN ? AND ?", eventIn[:start_date], eventIn[:end_date]])

    respond_to do |format|
       format.html
       format.json { render json: @events }
       format.js
    end
end
```

One other small thing - the `form_tag` `class` should be set like so:

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => 'events', :action => 'dateFilter'}, :class => 'date_form', :remote => true) do %>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I didn't realize that it was being passed as a hash, it makes a lot more sense now.  I have a landing page called "dateFilter.html.erb".  Do I just render that in the "success" Ajax event?