# rails datetimepicker clearing date selected from input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datepicker, datetimepicker, ransack

I'm using ransack gem with datetimepicker.js and bootstrap to execute an date range search. The query is ok, but when the template is rendered, it not keeping in the view the date value that I selected before.

This is the response URL:

http://localhost:3000/batches?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q%5Bcost_centre_id_in%5D=&q%5Bcreated_at_gteq%5D=yyyy-00-Dom+12%3Aii&q%5Bcreated_at_lteq%5D=yyyy-00-5%C2%AA+12%3Aii&button=

This is index method in controller:

```
def index
    @ransack = Multicast::Batch.includes(:cost_centre).where(customer_id: current_customer_id || '---')
      .order('scheduled_to DESC, created_at DESC')
    .search(params[:q])

    @batches = @ransack.result.page(params[:page]||1).per(10).decorate
  end
```

This is the index HTML code:

```
.form-group
            = f.label :created_at_gteq, " FROM: "

            .input-group.date.calendar
              = f.text_field :created_at_gteq, class: "form-control"
              span.input-group-addon
                span.glyphicon.glyphicon-calendar


            = f.label :created_at_lteq, " TO: "
            | &nbsp;
            .input-group.date.calendar
              = f.text_field :created_at_lteq, class: "form-control"
              span.input-group-addon
                span.glyphicon.glyphicon-calendar
```

This is the datetimepicker function:

```
$(function () {
    $('.calendar').datetimepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve your problem with ransacker:

https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/wiki/Using-Ransackers

Other solution that may help you ( It didn't work for me, but still you can try ):

https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/issues/265#issuecomment-51211135

This [gem](https://github.com/davidbrusius/ransack_advanced_search) has the following features: ***Saved Searches, scoped by contexts, to persist search params and use it in the future;*** and it is compatible with ransack.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13849342/6509507) from SO may help too.

I hope it helps